# Calculate the correct time with respect to time zone without daylight saving time

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

Currently, I used method to calculate the time with respect to the timezone, as below

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-HH:mm").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Denver"));

DateTime f = fmt.parseDateTime("2014-09-20T20:00:33+07:00");
```

but it also considers the daylight saving time in account to calculate the time.
So, Anyone has any method/workaround to calculate the time without considering the DST.(i.e. I don‘t want to add the DST in my calculated time).

Comment: Why do you want to calculate an artifical time as if America/Denver had not switched to summer time? Where is the practical relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still wondering why you want to calculate local standard time which is of no practical relevance IMHO but okay, here you go:

```
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Denver");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(dtz);

DateTime f = fmt.parseDateTime("2014-09-20T20:00:33+07:00");
System.out.println("JODA-DT=" + f); // 2014-09-20T07:00:33.000-06:00
System.out.println("STD-OFFSET=" + dtz.getStandardOffset(f.getMillis()) / 3600000); // -7
f = f.withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(dtz.getStandardOffset(f.getMillis())));
System.out.println("Standard-time=" + f); // 2014-09-20T06:00:33.000-07:00
```

Note: I have first corrected your wrong format pattern.

Comment: Actually, it is part of a requirement where time is required without adding DST into it. Time with DST creates more confusion to analyzed the Actual time, Thanks.